# Posting form data to 2 different destinations

Tags: html, forms, post

I have a form (A hotel booking form) with a list of hotels in a dropdown. There are fields for date, nights etc.

Here's the thing though -
Some of the hotels use booking system A, some of the hotels use booking system B. So, the destination page for the form data changes, as does the field names being used.

So for one hotel, the correct posting is:
https://bookingsystema.com/XBE/rez.aspx?hotel=24221&arrive=20%2F08%2F2013&nights=2&rooms=1&adult=2&promo=

for the other it would be:
https://bookingsystemb.com/tb3/index.cfm?arrivalDate=2013-08-20&nights=2&adults=1&promocode=&hotnum=HTO27588

I have looked at a number of options and tried a few ways, but can't get anything working. I tried with javascript but quickly ran out of knowledge of how to switch the destination of the form by looking at the hotel number.

Or another way might be to send the form data to a php file which could check which system, set up the correct format for that system (by renaming the fields) and then redirect to their booking engine page, only I haven't found how you can read the post data and then re-post it onto another system.

Any pointers would be most welcome

Comment: This is a matter of an `if;else;` and can be done with JS or PHP, this is very similar to ecommerce and the different payment systems.

Comment: What have you tried? You could use server side script (for example PHP) for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when user selects A or B, then the form submit-catcher will check which one it is, and then redirect really quick?

```
<?

if ($_POST['submit_trigger']) {
    if ($_POST['which_hotel'] == 'A') {
        Header('Location: http://www.a-hotel-link.com/?blabla=variables');
        Die();
    } elseif ($_POST['which_hotel'] == 'B') {
        Header('Location: http://www.b-hotel-link.com/?blabla=variables');
        Die();
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="which_hotel" value="A" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_trigger" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Of course the `which_hotel` should be a radio-button and etc.

Comment: Thanks, I got that to work, I can get the form to post and go to the 2 different URL's - but those variables from the form input - how do i get the form values into the header location address?

Comment: Im gonna give you the very most basic answer for this. Note that this should be done by more better function: `Header('Location: http://www.a-hotel-link.com/?hotnum=' . $_POST['hotnum'] . '');`